# Will the newsletter be implemented for all sites in the SE network?

Tags: discussion, newsletter

Currently, not all sites show the "get the newsletter" thing in the sidebar.

The one I'd most likely subscribe to would be a newsletter for Area51, since that's a site I visit very infrequently, but there doesn't seem to be a newsletter for it (yet?).

Comment: What exactly would the newsletter for Area 51 contain?

Comment: @Cody, new hot proposals, proposals that are nearing end of commitment phase. New sites in beta. New graduates out of beta. I'd quite like to be informed when new site designs get posted too. Oh and any of the hot discussions.

Comment: Thanks @Benjol, that's almost exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can find all of the newsletters over at https://stackexchange.com/newsletters instead of waiting to stumble across the relevant sidebar advert.

As far as I can see, newsletters are already available for *all* of the currently active Q&A sites, and I presume will be available for all future ones as well.

I assume that because Area 51 is not really a network Q&A site it doesn't have a newsletter, possibly you need to change this in to a feature request if an A51 newsletter is what you're after.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the pointer to the newsletter page, I didn't know about that one. I posted [a new feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102553/160382) instead of changing this post.