# Implement a Newsletter for Area51

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

At https://stackexchange.com/newsletters there's a list of newsletters one can subscribe to. Since Area51 is not exactly the same format as the other sites within the SE network, it doesn't have a newsletter by default.

However, I'm registered at this site, and I'd like a newsletter since I don't visit as frequently as I do at most other sites.

As per the comments on my [initial question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102538/160382) (thanks to Benjol for mind-reading skills), this newsletter could contain:

- new proposals
- proposals that are nearing end of commitment phase
- new sites in beta
- new graduates out of beta
- betas that "need work" in some area. For example, (at the time I'm writing this), [Travel](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel) needs work on *questions/day* and *visits/day*.

Comment: I love this idea.  I would also suggest a newsletter also contain some abbreviated FAQ for newbies, a do's and don't's of the sites, ways to navigate.